# Get Unix/Linux system architecture using Mono

Tags: c#, architecture, mono

How can I get the current OS architecture using Mono?

Comment: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Can-You-Programmatically-Determining-Architecture-x86-x64-IA64-td3858106.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *may be* possible.

There's no way to do this is proper plain Jane .NET, [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) (where'd you expect this to be) doesn't expose it.

But Mono has the `Mono.Unix.Native` namespace (you'll need to add a reference to Mono.Posix.dll), which has the [Syscall class](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall).  This exposes [`uname`](http://ss64.com/bash/uname.html), which may give you what you want; this doesn't seem terribly standard across Linux/Unix versions, and I'm not sure how much normalizing Mono is doing here.

```
Mono.Unix.Native.Utsname results;
var res = Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.uname(out results);
if(res != 0)
{
  throw new Exception("Syscall failed!");
}
```

When I run this on my Mac, `results.machine` is set to `x86_64`.  I don't have a Linux machine handy to test for consistency; but this would be the way to do it if there's any at all.